# cvShowImage blocks in secondary thread when OpenCV is built with Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

I am working on some legacy OpenCV code (old C style, too big to convert to C++ style) and using threading to try to speed things up. Displaying is done in its own thread with a buffered image protected by a mutex. Threads are implemented using C++11 std::threads.

When on a system that has OpenCV built with the standard GTK gui, everything works great (>10 hours of testing on the current version). When working on a system that has Qt as the gui (setup during OpenCV build), the call to cvShowImage blocks, however, the other threads keep on going.

The architecture is something like this:

```
main(){
    cvNamedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL | CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | CV_GUI_EXPANDED);

    std::thread imageAcquisition(&TrackerBase::getImageLoop, this);
    std::thread displayThread(&TrackerBase::displayLoop, this); 

    while (run_) {
        if (newImage_) {
            newImage_ = false;
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(img_mutex_);
                cvCopyImage(img_, img_process_);
            }
            // do processing, will dump an image into img_result_ while locking img_result_mutex_
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(process_mutex_);
                process();
            }
            newResult_ = true;
        }
    }
}

//Grab an image from a camera, dumps it in img_ while locking img_mutex_
void TrackerBase::getImageLoop(){
    while(run_){
        if (!getImage()) {
            newImage_ = true;
        }
    }
}

void TrackerBase::displayLoop(){
    if(display_) {
        while (run_) {
            if(newResult_) {
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(img_result_mutex_);
                    cvCopy(img_result_, img_result_display_);
                }
                cvShowImage("Image", img_result_display_);
                newResult_ = false;
                cvWaitKey(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `run_`, `newImage_`, and `newResult_` are all atomic.

Does anybody have any idea as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that **ALL** highgui elements must be created and used in the same thread. That includes window creation, image showing, waitkey, window destruction. So in this case the `cvNamedWindow` line needed to go into the `TrackerBase::displayLoop()` function (ideally inside of the first `if`).